# session are not working properly in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, session

I am making an webapp to add image in MongoDB using image url. But when I'm using `userFilter` using `Session` it is not working and anything related `Session` are not working.

I have already use command "meteor add session " but again its not working 
my `start.js` code is:

```
Images=new Mongo.Collection("images");
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Session.set("imageLimit",8);
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        console.log(new Date());
    })

    Template.images.helpers({
        images:function(){
            if(Session.get("userFilter")){
                return Images.find({createBy:Session.get("userFilter")},{sort: {date:-1,rating:-1}});
            } else {
                return Images.find({},{sort:{date:-1,rating:-1}});
            }
        },
        getUser:function(user_id){
            var user=Meteor.users.findOne({_id:user_id});
            if(user) {
                return user.username;
            } else {
                return "none"
            }
        }
    });

    Template.body.helpers({
        username:function(){
            if(Meteor.user()) {
                return Meteor.user().username;
                //  return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    });

    Template.images.events({
        'click .js-image':function(event){
            $(event.target).css("width","50px");
        },
        'click .btn-del':function(event){
            var id=this._id;
            $("#"+id).hide('slow',function(){
                Images.remove({"_id":id});
            });
        },
        'click .js-rate':function(event){
            var rating=$(event.currentTarget).data("userrating");
            console.log(rating); 
            var image_id=this.id;
            Images.update({_id:image_id},{$set:{rating:rating}});
        },
        'click .js-form-show':function(event){
            $("#add-form").modal('show');
        },
        'click .js-click-name':function(event){
            Session.set("userFilter",this.createBy);
        }
    });

    Template.img_text.events({
        'submit .js-form':function(event){
            var img_src,img_alt;
            img_src=event.target.img_src.value;

            img_alt=event.target.img_alt.value;

            Images.insert({
                img_src:img_src,
                img_alt:img_alt,
                date:new Date(),
                createBy:Meteor.user()._id
            });

            return false;
        },
    });
 }
```

my html code is:

```html
<head>
    <title>Meteor JS</title>

</head>



<body>
    {{> img_text}}

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
 {{> loginButtons}}
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to mySite {{username}}!</h1>



{{> images}}

</div>

</body>

<template name="img_text">
<div class="modal fade" id="add-form">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title">
                <h2>Image Form</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="js-form">
                      <input type="text" name="img_src">
                      <br/><input type="text" name="img_alt">
                      <button class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
                      </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" >cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<template name="images">
    {{#if currentUser }}
    <div id="btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success js-form-show" >Add Image</button>
    </div>
{{/if}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each images}}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="{{_id}}">
            <div class="thumbnail">

    <img class="js-image" src="{{img_src}}" alt="{{img_alt}}"/>
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>Rating : {{rating}}</h3>
        <p>{{img_alt}}</p>
        <p>
            User:
         <a href="#" class="js-click-name">{{getUser createBy}}</a></p>

        <p> 
            {{>starsRating  mutable=true class="js-rate" id=_id}}
        </p>

<button class="btn-del btn btn-warning">delete</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Nicky - your question is a little unclear. What precisely goes wrong with the Session? Can you highlight the relevant code, and give perhaps an example of an error you are getting?

Comment: no error is showing in my terminal window just myapp is notworking proprly or the session command are not working and i dont know why

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to explain clearly what goes wrong (by saying what you were expecting it to do, and saying what it actually did), that would help.

Comment: thanxx for rply .My app is storing images in mongo db and then showing it in localhost.But when im applying filter that the current login user iamges will show only.For this i have to captur ecurrent session so that i can show the user images which is currently login.but when i m clicking the use it shows nothing.